# Control message offset in Kafka consumer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

The implementation was in Python. Using confluent_kafka.

I have a consumer object to poll message from a kafka topic. The messages are used for further processing by other big objects and I cannot afford to back up the object after each message processing due to the size.

I periodically dump the object and then manually commit the consumer. Below are the sample codes I implemented.

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError, TopicPartition

c = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'myserver',
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'smallest'},
    'enable.auto.commit': "false"
})
c.subscribe(['mytopic'])

offsets = {} 

for i in range(10):
    msg = c.poll()

    if msg.error():
        continue

    par = msg.partition()
    off = msg.offset() 
    offsets[p] = off 

c.commit(async=False) 

print(offsets)
```

When I ran this code the 2nd time, I expect the message offset, if from the same partition, should be the next one, i.e. +1, from the previous offset as printed.

But the offsets advanced a lot. A few hundreds more.

I also tried to manually assign the positions as follows:

```
lst_part = []

for par, off in offsets.items():
    lst_part.append(TopicPartition('mytopic', par, off))

c.assign(lst_part)

# then start polling messages
```

The newly polled messages are not the assigned offset + 1.

Answer (score 1):

`c.commit(async=False)` will commit all consumed partitions for which a message has been returned from the client to the application by the `poll()` call.

If you want more fine grained control over which offsets to commit you can either pass an explicit `[TopicPartition(..)]` list to `commit()` (make sure to commit last_message_offset+1) or disable `auto.offset.store` and explicitly call `store_offsets()` for the messages/offsets you wish to store for a future `commit()` call.

Do note that [`store_offsets()`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/confluent_kafka/src/Consumer.c#L727) is only available on master and is not yet available in a released version of the confluent-kafka-python client, but soon will be.